# ref.downloadURL() not executing or returning url once uploadTask is success

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

**Goal**: To upload data to Firebase storage and return a url of the public download link.
**Problem**: The function that return the link is not updating my data structure which leads me to think that the link is not available yet or the function is erring out somehow.
**Code**:

```
uploadTask.observe(.success){ snapshot in
                uploadData["comments"] = "0"
                uploadData["likes"] = "0"
                uploadData["name"] = "JGTech"
                snapshot.metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL(completion: { (url, err) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err!)
                    }else{
                        uploadData["image"] = url?.absoluteString
                    }
                    uploadData["image"] = url?.absoluteString
                })
```

**Data structure after**:
uploadData = ["name": "JGTech", "comments": "0", "likes": "0"] without image key-value pair.

**[7/7/2020]**
I have tried different variation of implementing this functionality and all the results show that this function is not executing. Possibly due to this function being async. Did a breakpoint at the downloadURL line and that function is completely skipped.

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate how you are observing that your data structure is not being updated.  Keep in mind that downloadURL is asynchronous and don't complete immediately.

Comment: What is uploadData?

Comment: uploadData is the data structure that is not getting populated with an image key-value pair

Comment: @DougStevenson How do I wait until the download link is ready? Is there a wait function or for loop I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this worked and not the other way. It seems like I had to do all my logic within the block that has variable linkString defined

```
            uploadTask.observe(.success){ snapshot in
                var linkString: String = ""
                uploadData["comments"] = "0"
                uploadData["likes"] = "0"
                uploadData["name"] = "JGTech"
                ref.downloadURL(completion: { (url, err) in
                    if err == nil {
                        if let link = url {
                            linkString = link.absoluteString
                            uploadData["image"] = linkString
```